# Charging Members in a Loop using PayPal REST API

Tags: php, api, rest, paypal

I want to charge my website members weekly. I have stored their Credit Card Information with their Address, Phone #, City, State, etc in a table.

I am using PayPal REST API with PHP.

Here is my code:

```
while ($row2 = $res2->fetch_assoc ())
{                   
    // ### Address
    // Base Address object used as shipping or billing
    // address in a payment. [Optional]
    $addr = new Address ();

    if ($row2 ['billing_address'])
        $addr->setLine1 ($row2 ['billing_address']);

    if ($row2 ['billing_address2'])
        $addr->setLine2 ($row2 ['billing_address2']);

    if ($row2 ['billing_city'])
        $addr->setCity ($row2 ['billing_city']);

    if ($row2 ['billing_state'])
        $addr->setState ($row2 ['billing_state']);

    if ($row2 ['billing_zip'])
        $addr->setPostal_code ($row2 ['billing_zip']);

    $addr->setCountry_code ("US");

    if ($row2 ['billing_phone'])
        $addr->setPhone ($row2 ['billing_phone']);

    // Decrypt Credit Cart #
    $credit_card_number = decrypt ($row2 ['cc_number'], 'hassan');
    $cc_name_array = explode (" ", $row2 ['cc_name']);
    $cc_name_array_count = count ($cc_name_array);

    $cc_f_name = $cc_name_array [0];
    $cc_l_name = "";
    for ($i = 1; $i < $cc_name_array_count; $i++)
    {
        $cc_l_name .= str_replace (array ("&", "."), "", $cc_name_array [$i]) . " ";
    }
    $cc_l_name = trim ($cc_l_name);

    // ### CreditCard
    // A resource representing a credit card that can be
    // used to fund a payment.
    $card = new CreditCard ();
    if (strtolower ($row2 ['cc_type']) == "visa")
    {
        $card->setType ('visa');
    }
    elseif (strtolower ($row2 ['cc_type']) == "mastercard")
    {
        $card->setType ('mastercard');
    }
    elseif (strtolower ($row2 ['cc_type']) == "discover cards")
    {
        $card->setType ('discover');
    }
    elseif (strtolower ($row2 ['cc_type']) == "american express")
    {
        $card->setType ('amex');
    }
    $card->setNumber ($credit_card_number);
    $card->setExpire_month ($row2 ['cc_expiry_month']);
    $card->setExpire_year ($row2 ['cc_expiry_year']);
    $card->setCvv2 ($row2 ['cc_cvv']);
    $card->setFirst_name ($cc_f_name);
    $card->setLast_name ($cc_l_name);
    $card->setBilling_address ($addr);

    // ### FundingInstrument
    // A resource representing a Payer's funding instrument.
    // Use a Payer ID (A unique identifier of the payer generated
    // and provided by the facilitator. This is required when
    // creating or using a tokenized funding instrument)
    // and the `CreditCardDetails`
    $fi = new FundingInstrument ();
    $fi->setCredit_card ($card);

    // ### Payer
    // A resource representing a Payer that funds a payment
    // Use the List of `FundingInstrument` and the Payment Method
    // as 'credit_card'
    $payer = new Payer ();
    $payer->setPayment_method ("credit_card");
    $payer->setFunding_instruments (array ($fi));

    // ### Amount
    // Let's you specify a payment amount.
    $amount = new Amount ();
    $amount->setCurrency ("USD");
    //$amount->setTotal ("1.00");
    $amount->setTotal ($row ['billing_cost']);

    // ### Transaction
    // A transaction defines the contract of a
    // payment - what is the payment for and who
    // is fulfilling it. Transaction is created with
    // a `Payee` and `Amount` types
    $transaction = new Transaction ();
    $transaction->setAmount ($amount);
    $transaction->setDescription ("Commission deducted for the sold property.");

    // ### Payment
    // A Payment Resource; create one using
    // the above types and intent as 'sale'
    $payment = new Payment ();
    $payment->setIntent ("sale");
    $payment->setPayer ($payer);
    $payment->setTransactions (array ($transaction));



    // ### Create Payment
    // Create a payment by posting to the APIService
    // using a valid ApiContext (See bootstrap.php for more on `ApiContext`)
    // The return object contains the status;
    try
    {
        $payment->create ($apiContext);
    }
    catch (\PPConnectionException $ex)
    {
        echo "Exception: " . $ex->getMessage () . PHP_EOL;
        var_dump ($ex->getData());
        exit (1);
    }


    if ($payment->getId ())
    {
        $br_date = time ();
        $insert = "INSERT INTO `billing_reports`
                    (`sh_id`, `listing_id`, `billed_person_type`, `billed_person_id`, `cc_type`, `cc_name`, `cc_number`, `cc_expiry_month`, `cc_expiry_year`, `cc_cvv`, `billing_amount`, `payment_id`, `br_date`, `status`)
                    VALUES ('" . $row ['sh_id'] . "', '" . $row ['listing_id'] . "', '" . $row2 ['member_type'] . "', '" . $row2 ['member_id'] . "', '" . $row2 ['cc_type'] . "', '" . $row2 ['cc_name'] . "', '" . $row2 ['cc_number'] . "', '" . $row2 ['cc_expiry_month'] . "', '" . $row2 ['cc_expiry_year'] . "', '" . $row2 ['cc_cvv'] . "', '" . $row ['billing_cost'] . "', '" . $payment->getId () . "', '" . $br_date . "', 1)";
        $GLOBALS ['mysqli']->query ($insert) or die ($GLOBALS ['mysqli']->error . __LINE__);
        //unset ($addr, $card, $fi, $payer, $amount, $transaction, $payment);
    }
}
```

Each iteration of loop gets a new member from the table and fill his information into REST API variables.

But the problem is this that this loop works fine if 2 or more consecutive members have same Credit Card info. When info gets changed the transaction doesn't pass through.

I am not an expert in PayPal. Therefore, need help from you guys. I think the issue is with $payment object. It doesn't get instantiated with new value. Any kind of help would be great. I have already spent 3 days on this :(

Comment: Offtopic: Are you sure you want to be storing creditcard data? Take a look at our vault functionality: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/store-a-credit-card/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is that in loop '$apiContext' object is loosing its values in subsequent iterations. So, the easy and quick fix (not sure if it is the right fix) is to initialize '$apiContext' in each iteration. Like this...

```
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc ())
{

    // ### Api Context
    // Pass in a `PayPal\Rest\ApiContext` object to authenticate 
    // the call. You can also send a unique request id 
    // (that ensures idempotency). The SDK generates
    // a request id if you do not pass one explicitly. 
    $apiContext = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential(
            '<client-id>',
            '<secret>'));
```

This way when the following line of code is executed the '$apiContext' object will have the values.

```
$payment->create ($apiContext);
```

Initially '$apiContext' object is initialized in 'bootstrap.php' file. And it is one time initialization. Now theoretically this should work for all loop iterations but it doesn't work. To access 'ApiContext' Class you need to include the following lines of code at the top also.

```
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
```